# Finding eigenvalues of a lower/upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

If we have a matrix:
\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & -8 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Now the matrix is in upper triangular form and $\det(A) = 1 \times (-8) \times 5$ and
$\operatorname{tr}(A) = 1 - 8 + 5$
can we say that $\{1,-8,5\}$ are eigenvalues of $A$ and why?

Comment: The fact that the determinant equals $a\times b\times c$ and the trace equal $a+b+c$ does not imply in and of itself that the eigenvalues are $a+b+c$. For example, the eigenvalues of the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $1$, $-1$ and $0$ are different from the eigenvalues of the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $2$, $-2$, and $0$, but both have the same determinant and the same trace.

Comment: Elementary row operations do not respect the eigenvalues: if $A$ is obtained from $B$ by performing an elementary row operation on $B$, then it is not necessarily the case that $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues. This is trivial to see if you for elementary row operations that involve multiplication by nonzero constants different from $1$, but also others. For example, the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{rr}1&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right)$ has eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$; exchanging  rows gives you the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{rr}0&-1\\ 1&0\end{array}\right)$, with eigenvalues $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: Or the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&2\\2&0\end{array}\right)$ has eigenvalues $2,-2$; adding the second row to the first row gives $\left(\begin{array}{cc}2&2\\2&0\end{array}\right)$ has eigenvalues $1\pm\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Ok so operations on the matrix change eigenvalues ,I'll reformat the question to be about eigenvalues of lower/upper triangular matrices

Comment: @YoussefMohamed, you keep using the ambiguous phrase *operations*. There are different kinds of operations. *Row operations* do not preserve eigenvalues, nor do *column operations* on their own. However, the operation of simultaneously applying an elementary row operation on one side of the matrix and the inverse column operation on the other side *does* preserve the eigenvalues, i.e. $A \mapsto E^{-1}AE$, where $E$ is an elementary row operation.

Comment: A triangular matrix's eigenvalues are precisely the diagonal entries. This is not *because of* the trace and determinant, however. For example, $118$ can be written as the sum of a triple of nonzero integers in four different ways, each triple of which has the same product. So knowing that you have an upper triangular matrix with determinant equal to $37800$ and trace equal to $118$ would not allow you to determine the eigenvalues; they could be $14$, $50$, and $54$; or they could be $15$, $40$, and $63$; or they could be $18$, $30$, and $70$; or they could be $21$, $25$, and $72$.

Comment: We can say the eigenvalues are the diagonal entries because the diagonal entries are precisely the values of $\lambda$ for which $A-\lambda I$ is non-invertible.

Answer (score 0):

For any matrix the roots of the polynomial  $p(\lambda) = \det(A- \lambda I)$ are the eigenvalues.

In the particular if $A$ is upper triangular then this determinant is simply

$$ (a_{11}- \lambda)...(a_{nn} - \lambda)$$

Hence the eigenvalues of $A$ can be read of the diagonal since they are precisely the values for which the above polynomial is equal to $0$.